# web system permissions best practices

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, permissions

I have an asp.net MVC 3 system which different actions have different permissions.

All the permissions are managed using attributes that defines the required user permission.

I would also like to remove any buttons (or links) that the user is not permitted to click on.

Is there any way to do so without doing a lot of if-s in my views ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to do so without doing a lot of if-s in my views ?

You could write custom HTML helpers that will generate those buttons. For example:

```
@Html.Button("button text", "role1,role2");
```

The custom helper will check whether the current user posses one of the required roles and only in this case generate the corresponding button.

For example:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString Button(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string buttonText, string roles)
    {
        var rolesSplit = (roles ?? string.Empty).Split(',');
        var user = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        var button = new TagBuilder("button");
        button.SetInnerText(buttonText);
        return new HtmlString(button.ToString());
    }
}
```